# Control height of longtable's last page

Tags: longtable

I want to control table, created by `longtable` enwironment such way that it would  have pagebreak before last two lines if the rest of the table would be longer than some height (it depends on height of text, that follows the table and should be fully on last page with at least two last columns of table). The last line and text after table is static block, I put it into `lastfoot`. But line before last should be always on the same page with last line.

Here is the shortest working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\f@st
\f@st={}
\def\pr@line#1{#1\global\f@st={}}
\def\RPOline#1#2{\pr@line{\the\f@st}\global\f@st={#1&#2\cr\hline}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}
\newsavebox\l@stb@x
\def\RPOb@g{
    \global\savebox{\l@stb@x}{\hbox to\textwidth{\vbox to 10cm{some text\vfill bottom}}}
    \begin{longtable}{|C{1cm}|C{5cm}|}
    \hline N& Name\cr\hline\endfirsthead
    \endhead\endfoot
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\usebox{\l@stb@x}}\endlastfoot
}
\newtoks\old@utput
\newdimen\texth@
\old@utput=\expandafter{\the\output}
\def\ts@{\texth@=\textheight\advance\texth@ by -\ht\l@stb@x\advance\texth@ by -5mm\relax
    \setbox0=\vbox{\unvbox255}\ifdim\ht0<\texth@
    \setbox255=\vbox{\unvbox0\pr@line{\the\f@st}}\else
    \setbox255=\vbox{\unvbox0}\fi
    \the\old@utput
    \global\output=\expandafter{\the\old@utput}}
\def\PRO@nd{
    \global\output={\ts@}\cr\pagebreak
    \pr@line{\the\f@st}
    \end{longtable}
}
\newenvironment{RPOtable}{\RPOb@g}{\PRO@nd}
\makeatother
\newcount\tstcnt
\def\fillt#1{\ifnum\tstcnt>0\global\advance\tstcnt by -1\relax #1\fillt{#1}\fi}
\def\filltbl#1#2{\global\tstcnt=#1\relax\fillt{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{RPOtable}
    \filltbl{31}{\RPOline{a}{Sample line}}
    \RPOline{L}{Last line}
\end{RPOtable}
\end{document}
```

When I put `\cr\pagebreak` into `\PRO@nd` (like written above) I get no errors but have empty lines in table and the table always breaks on `\pagebreak`. If I omit `\pagebreak`, line marked as "Last line" stays on previous page, and there's still an empty table line after it.

**Question**

How can I make "unbreaking" of page with `longtable`? I can't do `\vsplit` bacause it is already a box. Also I always have error messages `Misplased \noalign` if I don't put `\cr` before of `\pagebreak`.

Comment: I can't follow your code (nor do I understand the description of the problem) and I know something about longtable's internals, please _always_ post a _complete_ small document that demonstrates the problem, not a series of processable fragments.

Comment: `\cr` is not a latex command but as longtable only breaks between rows, you are only allowed to use `\pagebreak` immediately after `\\ `.

Comment: You have `\ifx\relax#1`  but it appears that `#1` is always `\the` so the test is always false. It is very hard to guess what this is indented to do.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, this `longtable` don't work with \\, but work with `\cr` (that's because of specific column types - for central alignment: I have errors `misplaced noalign` with \\). As for `\ifx` I agree: this is my error, it do nothing.

Comment: If `\\ ` isn't working then there is an error in the document but it's impossible to comment on the code in the form presented here, sorry, you need to post a proper example document with a description of what the intended result is, otherwise I suspect not much can be done other than close the question as "unclear"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I did simplest example

Answer (score 3):

As documented in the longtable documentation the way to keep the final rows together is to put them into the last foot, or to use `\\*`.

The code as posted is in the wrong place so producing spurious cells hence the extra vertical line segments, and is missing `%` at ends of lines so introducing white space. If I understand the problem there should be no need to switch output routines. Certainly switching output routine inside the table seems brave.

You need `\arraybackslash` after `\centering` to use `\\` in this context (or use `\tabularnewline` never `\cr` except in internal code.

This version puts the last 4 rows in the last foot below there is a version that uses 
nopagebreak penalties (which as noted in comments probably need some further tweaks).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\raggedbottom
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\def\samplerow#1#2{%
\ifnum#1>0
#2\\\hline
\afterfi
\expandafter\samplerow\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}{#2}%
\fi}
\def\afterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}


\raggedbottom
\begin{document}


\makeatother
\begin{longtable}{@{}|C{1cm}|C{5cm}|@{}}
\hline
N&Name\\\hline\endhead
\samplerow{4}{a&sample line}
\noalign{\nobreak\smallskip\noindent\parbox\textwidth{Last line}}\endlastfoot
\samplerow{25}{a&Sample Line}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

---

The following generates 31 lines plus a head and following paragraph, ensuring at least 4 rows are kept with the end of the table.

[image]

You could normally just use `\nopagebreak` but `\hline` allows page breaking at `\hline` so this substitutes a non page break version for the last few rows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\raggedbottom
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\makeatletter
\def\samplerow#1#2{%
\ifnum#1>0
#2\\
\ifnum#1<5 
\nopagebreak
  \multispan\LT@cols
     \unskip\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hfill\cr
\nopagebreak
\else
\hline
\fi
\afterfi
\expandafter\samplerow\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}{#2}%
\fi}
\def\afterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}
\makeatother

\raggedbottom
\begin{document}


\makeatother
\begin{longtable}{@{}|C{1cm}|C{5cm}|@{}}
\hline
N&Name\\\hline\endhead
\noalign{\nobreak\smallskip\noindent\parbox\textwidth{Last line}}\endlastfoot
\samplerow{31}{a&Sample Line}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing to my errors. But your variant don't solves my problem. In real the table fills by external soft that makes latex file and run `pdflatex`, it can't do "right" table, it just fills all rows. So, I really need to do something with `\output` or modify `longtable` by my own needs.

Comment: The main my problem is to store last table row in some token. It doesn't work :(

Comment: @Eddy_Em If you ask unanswerable questions it's unlikely that you get answers that you want. You have given no indication of why you need to change the output routine (there can't be any need to change it within the table) nor given any indication of why you need ore the last row in a way different to the mechanism shown here.

Comment: That's simple: document format require next to the last table line to be present on the same page with last (total sum) line and footer. In common case I want to have a strict control of table: the best way would be an ability to `\vsplit` its content into separate lines to leave N lines on current page and push remain lines to next.

Comment: I think, I should make another question.

Comment: @Eddy_Em That is exactly what the code here does, ensures (in this case) the last 4 lines stay together. Did you try it? The whole point of longtable is _not_ to use vsplit but to use the output routine.

Comment: Your code is wrong: try `\samplerow{29}{a&Sample Line}` and you will see, that it doesn't work!

Comment: @Eddy_Em hmm  a breakable point leaked in somewhere, it would just need a \nobreak adding somewhere but anyway I posted a simpler version using the other method mentioned in the documentation for keeping rows together, putting them in the last foot.

Comment: No, I tried to use \nopagebreak right after last line: it don't work, unfortunately. Another way - to put last line into last footer - I can't do too, because I have no idea how to put table line into token than won't break everything by its `&`'s